# Programming a Discord bot in Python- I have multiple client.events, but only one works at a time

Tags: python, discord.py

I have three client events that trigger when someone says a specific word, but only one of them works at a time. They all start with something like this-

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("dog"):
```

For some reason, only the event that I put below the other two works. Not sure why, any tips?

Comment: would you mind showing the code for all three events ?
I mean feel free to hide the code in the functions, I'd just like to see the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client receives an event (reaction, message etc.) from Discord. And @client.event catches them.
You should put similar tasks under the same event.
Maybe you can try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("dog"):
     await message.channel.send("...")
  else if message.content.startswith("cat"):
     await message.channel.send("...")
```